# Finding Fourier series and evaluating at a point

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Ive been asked to find the fourier series of the following [image: periodic function]

Need help with finishing the question, i have included my work so far below:[image]

[image]

and following that i need help with the final part of the question:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the correct expression for the coefficients $a_n$, $n\ge1$.  However, there must have been an error in your arithmetic for carrying out the integral

$$a_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi (x^2-\pi^2)^2\cos(nx)\,dx=\frac{48(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}$$

Also, we need the term $a_0$, which is

$$a_0=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (x^2-\pi^2)^2\,dx=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}$$

So, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=(x^2-\pi^2)^2\\\\
&=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{48(-1)^{n}}{n^4}\cos(nx)
\end{align}$$

Now, for $x=\pi$, $f(x)=0$. Furthermore, $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(\pi)&=0\\\\
&=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{48(-1)^{n}}{n^4}\cos(n\pi)\\\\
&=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{48(-1)^{n}}{n^4}(-1)^n\\\\
0&=\frac{8\pi^4}{15}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{48}{n^4}\tag1
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, we see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

as was to be determined!

Comment: I know that When x=π, cos(nπ)=(-1)^n but im still stuck

Comment: Where are you stuck?  I'd like to help more

Comment: Im stuck on finding bn

Comment: Oh.  The coefficients on the $\sin(nx)$ terms are all $0$.  This is because $f(x)$ is even while thebsine function is odd.

Comment: so is bn=0 since sin(nx) is 0?

Comment: Not quite.  $\sin(nx)$ is not $0$ of course.  But $\sin(nx)$ is an odd function.  Since $f(x)$ is an even function, then $f(x)\sin(nx)$ is an odd function.  And the value of an  integral of any odd function over symmetric limits (here $-\pi$ to $+\pi$) is always $0$.  So all of the $b_n$ are $0$.

Comment: so if all the bn are 0 what value of bn do i get?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't understand.  If $b_n=0$  for all $n$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\sin(nx)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: im asking if i have my fourier series as F(x)=1/2a0 +an+bn, where is sub a0 and an, is the bn i sub in 0?

Comment: The Fourier series for $f(x)$ is $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)$$where $a_0=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,dx$, $a_n=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$, and $b_n=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$.  If $f(x)$ is even, as it is here, then all of the $b_n$ terms are $0$ and we have $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos(nx)$$

Comment: Thanks i understand it now

Comment: Pleased to hear.